I want to create a simple app with two buttons that send HEXCODE to a USB Relay
I have a USB relay plugged in to my android device. The app 'Serial USB Terminal' in google play store works perfect, however I don't want the settings and other buttons. I need a simple app with two buttons On/OFF.
When On is pressed it sends A0 01 01 A2 as a hexcode to the switch and when Off is pressed is sends hex data A0 01 00 A1. I need the app to keep the USB connection or Connect automatically when loading the app.
Baud rate is 9600
Data bits = 8
Parity = 0
Stop bits = 1
I have an app in Android studio with two buttons however, I don't know the code to make this work. I have tried many templates from github with no joy, a lot of errors. I am a newbie when it comes to coding so I am learning as I go.
